# What does the number after the IP address represent in a MySQL connection error?

Tags: mysql, connection

I'd just like to know what the number '64' represents in MySQL connection error message:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (64) in /var/www/test.php

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perror 64
OS error code  64:  Machine is not on the network
```

...

Yeah, not a clue what that means either.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `perror` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/perror.html).

Answer (score 1):

Error 64 means the machine is not on the network.

Clearly the *machine* is on the network as it is your own, however the error might suggest that either MySQL is not running or may be running on a non standard port.

The PHP function `mysql_error()` will give you the textual representation of any error MySQL might throw.